# How to pass the parameters to get an object injected in guice?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice, logback, inject

I have a requirement where the class called MyAppender which has the parameters to initialize an object called "Client". But this "Client" should be created in the class called "LoggerModule" as it is the one injecting the dependencies. How do I do that? How can MyAppender tell LoggerModule to inject an instance with the parameter it wants? This is because MyAppender is a custom appender I wrote for logback.So only it can read the connfiguration xml file and obtain those values. Therefore he has the values. But those values are needed by LoggerModule to create an instance of client. How do I do this? Below is my MyAppender class.

```
public class MyAppender extends CustomAppender{
    @Inject
    @ClientAnnotation
    Client client;

    @Inject
    @ConnectOptionsAnnotation
    ConnectOptions connOpts;

     String url;
     String clientId;
     String topic;

    @Override
    public void init() {

            connOpts.setCleanSession(true);
            client.setCallback(this);
            client.connect();
            client.subscribe(topic);

    }

    @Override
    public void close() {

    }

    @Override
    public void handle(ILoggingEvent event) {


    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public String getClientId() {
        return clientId;
    }

    public void setClientId(String clientId) {
        this.clientId = clientId;
    }

    public String getTopic() {
        return topic;
    }

    public void setTopic(String topic) {
        this.topic = topic;
    }
}
```

Below is my module class that should inject an instance of client.

```
public class LoggerModule extends AbstractModule {

    MqttClient client;
    MqttConnectOptions connOpts;
    String url;
    String clientId;
    String topic;

    @Override
    protected void configure() {

    }

    @Provides
    @ClientAnnotation
    public Client provideClient() {
        client = new MqttClient(url, clientId);
        return client;
    }

    @Provides
    @ConnectOptionsAnnotation
    public ConnectOptions provideConnectOptions() {
        connOpts = new ConnectOptions();
        return connOpts;
    }


}
```

Client object needs the url and client id which the MyAppender class holds. How do I pass this to module class and get an object injected? I am totally new to guice.Please advice.

Comment: Simply add `MyAppender` as a parameter to your `@Provides` method.